# ViewPager Loads Blank Screen Until User Clicks Anywhere On Screen

Tags: android

I have implemented a viewpager adapter, the scrolling and contents returned works fine but the issue is, when I start my app, the screen is blank and only when I click anywhere on the blank screen does the viewpager load the first page (item 0) and everything else works fine after that. How can I get my app to load viewpager items without having to click first:

MainActivity:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userid, names, status, phonenumbers, rates, urls, dobyear, dobmonth, dobday, starrate));

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }
    });

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return this._userid.size();
}

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._userid.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == (object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay, ivRateBar;
    TextView tvName, tvPhoneNumber, tvRate, tvStatus, tvYear, tvDistance;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);
    ....
//set my textviews and imges
```

I tried:

```
private static int currentPage = 0;

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       currentPage = position;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, it works when I use a `handler.postDelayed`of half a second before setting my viewPager adapter, the logical reason behind this may be that the viewpager loads before all my data can be retrieved from the database.

Comment: Just another comment - using handler.postDelayed is not always guaranteed because the network connection may be slow and take longer than half a second to load, the best practice is to set view page adapter only after the data is returned from database, this will always set the adapter only if data is returned thereby eliminate setting the postDealyed - so in this case the set view pager adapter is called in the get json data class and not in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

After you get the data you are looking for try calling

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You just have to save the Adapter instance like so:

```
// Change this    
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userid, names, status, phonenumbers, rates, urls, dobyear, dobmonth, dobday, starrate));
// To this
ViewPagerAdapter myAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userid, names, status, phonenumbers, rates, urls, dobyear, dobmonth, dobday, starrate);
viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

...

// When the data is finished loading (wherever you load the data)
if (myAdapter != null) { 
      myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the adapter should refresh itself with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way worked for me:

```
if(viewPager.getAdapter()!=null){
    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    container.removeView(viewPager);
    container.addView(viewPager);
}
```